# Reasonably efficient pure-functional matrix product in Haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming

I know Haskell a little bit, and I wonder if it's possible to write something like a matrix-matrix product in Haskell that is all of the following:

1. **Pure-functional**: no `IO` or `State` monads in its type signature (I don't care what happens in the function body. *That is, I don't care if the function body uses monads, as long as the whole function is pure*). I may want to use this matrix-matrix product in a pure function.
2. **Memory-safe: no malloc or pointers**. I know that it's possible to "write C" in Haskell,
   but you lose memory safety. Actually writing this code in C and interfacing it with Haskell also loses memory safety.
3. **As efficient as, say, Java.** For concreteness, let's assume I'm talking about a simple triple loop, single precision, contiguous column-major layout (`float[]`, not `float[][]`) and matrices of size 1000x1000, and a single-core CPU. (If you are getting 0.5-2 floating point operations per cycle, you are probably in the ballpark.)

(I don't want this to sound like a challenge, but note that Java can satisfy **all** of the above easily.)

I already know that

1. **The triple loop implementation is not the most efficient one**. It's quite cache-oblivious. It's better to use a well-written [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) implementation in this particular case. However, one can not always count on a C library being available for what one is trying to do. I wonder if reasonably efficient code can be written in normal Haskell.
2. **Some people wrote whole research papers that demonstrate #3**. However, I'm not a computer science researcher. I wonder if it's possible to keep simple things simple in Haskell.
3. **The Gentle Introduction to Haskell has a matrix product implementation**. It wouldn't satisfy the above requirements though.

Addressing comments:

> I have three reasons: first, the "no malloc or pointers" requirement
>   is as yet ill-defined (I challenge you to write any piece of Haskell
>   code which uses no pointers);

I saw plenty of Haskell programs not using `Ptr`. Perhaps it refers to the fact that at the machine instruction level, pointers will be used? That's not what I meant. I was referring to the abstraction level of the Haskell source code.

> second, the attack on CS research is out of place (and furthermore I
>   can't imagine anything simpler than using code somebody else has
>   already written for you); third, there are many matrix packages on
>   Hackage (and the prep work for asking this question should include
>   reviewing and rejecting each).

It seems that your #2 and #3 are the same ("use existing libraries"). I'm interested in the matrix product as a simple test of what Haskell can do on its own, and whether it allows you to "keep simple things simple". I could have easily come up with a numerical problem that doesn't have any ready libraries, but then I'd have to explain the problem, whereas everyone already knows what a matrix product is.

> How can Java possibly satisfy 1.? Any Java method is essentially
>   `:: IORef Arg -> ... -> IORef This -> IO Ret`

This goes to the root of my question, actually (+1). While Java does not claim to track purity, Haskell does. In Java, whether the function is pure or not is indicated in the comments. I can claim that the matrix product is pure, even though I do mutation in the function body. **The question is whether Haskell's approach (purity encoded in the type system) is compatible with efficiency, memory-safety and simplicity.**

Comment: You say "I don't care what happens in the function body" and you say "no malloc or pointers".  Which one is it?  Do you want to clarify those points?

Comment: How can Java possibly satisfy 1.? Any Java method is essentially `:: IORef Arg -> ... -> IORef This -> IO Ret`.

Comment: `repa` can do this very nicely, but it uses `malloc` internally, as do most array libraries. Also, don't ask me to write the code on my phone, I've had to do that often enough already.

Comment: This question is clear and on-topic (and so I think shouldn't be closed); however, I'm downvoting. I have three reasons: first, the "no malloc or pointers" requirement is as yet ill-defined (I challenge you to write any piece of Haskell code which uses no pointers); second, the attack on CS research is out of place (and furthermore I can't imagine anything simpler than using code somebody else has already written for you); third, there are many matrix packages on Hackage (and the prep work for asking this question should include reviewing and rejecting each).

Comment: Hint: it is a one-liner when you use [`traverse2`](http://package.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.1.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa-Operators-Traversal.html#v:traverse2). Edit: this was a followup to my previous comment, not a response to Daniels.

Comment: Fixed link (autocorrect?): http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.1.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa-Operators-Traversal.html#v:traverse2

Comment: @DietrichEpp  "I don't care what happens in the function body" should be taken in its context: "pure functional".

Comment: @dflemstr I'd like to see your 1-liner. If it satisfies the 3 requirements, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: @DanielWagner I responded to your concerns in the "Edit". I think you misunderstood the intent of my question.

Comment: I hesitated to close vote, because as Daniel Wagner stated, it is both clear and on topic. However, it is an extremely narrow question that is unlikely to be of consequence to anyone, so I voted to close as "too localized". OP is actually trying to bring into question and/or flesh out evidence of what Haskell / purely functional style can do, but is going about it in a very awkward way.

Comment: @leftaroundabout please see the latest "Edit"

Comment: @DanBurton Can you suggest a better way to ask this question in a way that's not a subjective poll?

Comment: @DanielWagner: "How can one implement fast matrix multiplication in a pure functional style while maintaining simplicity?" is an exceptional question with wide applicability that deserves up-votes.  It is clear this is what OP was asking.  I can not understand why anyone would down-vote this question.

Comment: @PhilipJF I don't understand the downvotes and the overall negativity either.

Comment: @DietrichEpp *It is entirely possible use malloc in pure functions.* I know that. That's why I mention purity as req #1, and memory-safety **separately** as req #2. PLEASE re-read my question.

Comment: @Oleg2718281828: The reason I was asking in the first place is because you said, "I don't care what happens in the function body", and then you said, "don't use malloc".  Those are **outright contradictions,** which is why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I already responded to this and edited the main text.

Comment: Ever considered the ST monad?  It seems like it was made for just this kind of purpose.

Comment: I don't agree with the close votes. I think this question is clear, and has the potential to solicit interesting, well-written and *objective* answers (voting to reopen).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Thanks. I don't think your vote went through though.

Comment: The `State` monad is purely functional. Have you tried `STUArray`?

Comment: There's too much baggage in this question about programming paradigms, so its just going to elicit long, non-specific responses.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> As efficient as, say, Java. For concreteness, let's assume I'm talking about a simple triple loop, single precision, contiguous column-major layout (float[], not float[][]) and matrices of size 1000x1000, and a single-core CPU. (If you are getting 0.5-2 floating point operations per cycle, you are probably in the ballpark)

So something like

```java
public class MatrixProd {
    static float[] matProd(float[] a, int ra, int ca, float[] b, int rb, int cb) {
        if (ca != rb) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrices not fitting");
        }
        float[] c = new float[ra*cb];
        for(int i = 0; i < ra; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < cb; ++j) {
                float sum = 0;
                for(int k = 0; k < ca; ++k) {
                    sum += a[i*ca+k]*b[k*cb+j];
                }
                c[i*cb+j] = sum;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    static float[] mkMat(int rs, int cs, float x, float d) {
        float[] arr = new float[rs*cs];
        for(int i = 0; i < rs; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < cs; ++j) {
                arr[i*cs+j] = x;
                x += d;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sz = 100;
        float strt = -32, del = 0.0625f;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            sz = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        if (args.length > 1) {
            strt = Float.parseFloat(args[1]);
        }
        if (args.length > 2) {
            del = Float.parseFloat(args[2]);
        }
        float[] a = mkMat(sz,sz,strt,del);
        float[] b = mkMat(sz,sz,strt-16,del);
        System.out.println(a[sz*sz-1]);
        System.out.println(b[sz*sz-1]);
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float[] c = matProd(a,sz,sz,b,sz,sz);
        System.out.println(c[sz*sz-1]);
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double dur = (t1-t0)*1e-3;
        System.out.println(dur);
    }
}
```

I suppose? (I hadn't read the specs properly before coding, so the layout is row-major, but since the access pattern is the same, that doesn't make a difference as mixing layouts would, so I'll assume that's okay.)

I haven't spent any time on thinking about a clever algorithm or low-level optimisation tricks (*I* wouldn't achieve much in Java with those anyway). I just wrote the simple loop, because

> I don't want this to sound like a challenge, **but note that Java can satisfy all of the above easily**

And that's what Java gives **easily**, so I'll take that.

> (If you are getting 0.5-2 floating point operations per cycle, you are probably in the ballpark)

Nowhere near, I'm afraid, neither in Java nor in Haskell. Too many cache misses to reach that throughput with the simple triple loop.

Doing the same in Haskell, again no thinking about being clever, a plain straightforward triple loop:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module MatProd where

import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed

matProd :: UArray Int Float -> Int -> Int -> UArray Int Float -> Int -> Int -> UArray Int Float
matProd a ra ca b rb cb =
    let (al,ah)     = bounds a
        (bl,bh)     = bounds b
        {-# INLINE getA #-}
        getA i j    = a!(i*ca + j)
        {-# INLINE getB #-}
        getB i j    = b!(i*cb + j)
        {-# INLINE idx #-}
        idx i j     = i*cb + j
    in if al /= 0 || ah+1 /= ra*ca || bl /= 0 || bh+1 /= rb*cb || ca /= rb
         then error $ "Matrices not fitting: " ++ show (ra,ca,al,ah,rb,cb,bl,bh)
         else runSTUArray $ do
            arr <- newArray (0,ra*cb-1) 0
            let outer i j
                    | ra <= i   = return arr
                    | cb <= j   = outer (i+1) 0
                    | otherwise = do
                        !x <- inner i j 0 0
                        writeArray arr (idx i j) x
                        outer i (j+1)
                inner i j k !y
                    | ca <= k   = return y
                    | otherwise = inner i j (k+1) (y + getA i k * getB k j)
            outer 0 0

mkMat :: Int -> Int -> Float -> Float -> UArray Int Float
mkMat rs cs x d = runSTUArray $ do
    let !r = rs - 1
        !c = cs - 1
        {-# INLINE idx #-}
        idx i j = cs*i + j
    arr <- newArray (0,rs*cs-1) 0
    let outer i j y
            | r < i     = return arr
            | c < j     = outer (i+1) 0 y
            | otherwise = do
                writeArray arr (idx i j) y
                outer i (j+1) (y + d)
    outer 0 0 x
```

and the calling module

```
module Main (main) where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Array.Unboxed

import System.CPUTime
import Text.Printf

import MatProd

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let (sz, strt, del) = case args of
                            (a:b:c:_) -> (read a, read b, read c)
                            (a:b:_)   -> (read a, read b, 0.0625)
                            (a:_)     -> (read a, -32, 0.0625)
                            _         -> (100, -32, 0.0625)
        a = mkMat sz sz strt del
        b = mkMat sz sz (strt - 16) del
    print (a!(sz*sz-1))
    print (b!(sz*sz-1))
    t0 <- getCPUTime
    let c = matProd a sz sz b sz sz
    print $ c!(sz*sz-1)
    t1 <- getCPUTime
    printf "%.6f\n" (fromInteger (t1-t0)*1e-12 :: Double)
```

So we're doing almost exactly the same things in both languages. Compile the Haskell with `-O2`, the Java with javac

```
$ java MatrixProd 1000 "-13.7" 0.013
12915.623
12899.999
8.3592897E10
8.193
$ ./vmmult 1000 "-13.7" 0.013
12915.623
12899.999
8.35929e10
8.558699
```

And the resulting times are quite close.

And if we compile the Java code to native, with `gcj -O3 -Wall -Wextra --main=MatrixProd -fno-bounds-check -fno-store-check -o jmatProd MatrixProd.java`,

```
$ ./jmatProd 1000 "-13.7" 0.013
12915.623
12899.999
8.3592896512E10
8.215
```

there's still no big difference.

As a special bonus, the same algorithm in C (gcc -O3):

```
$ ./cmatProd 1000 "-13.7" 0.013
12915.623047
12899.999023
8.35929e+10
8.079759
```

So this reveals no fundamental difference between straightforward Java and straightforward Haskell when it comes to computationally intensive tasks using floating point numbers (when dealing with integer arithmetic on medium to large numbers, the use of GMP by GHC makes Haskell outperform Java's BigInteger by a huge margin for many tasks, but that is of course a library issue, not a language one), and both are close to C with this algorithm.

In all fairness, though, that is because the access pattern causes a cache-miss every other nanosecond, so in all three languages this computation is memory-bound.

If we improve the access pattern by multiplying a row-major matrix with a column-major matrix, all become faster, the gcc-compiled C finishes it 1.18s, java takes 1.23s and the ghc-compiled Haskell takes around 5.8s, which can be reduced to 3 seconds by using the llvm backend.

Here, the range-check by the array library really hurts. Using the unchecked array access (as one should, after checking for bugs, since the checks are already done in the code controlling the loops), GHC's native backend finishes in 2.4s, going via the llvm backend lets the computation finish in 1.55s, which is decent, although significantly slower than both C and Java. Using the primitives from `GHC.Prim` instead of the [array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array) library, the llvm backend produces code that runs in 1.16s (again, without bounds-checking on each access, but that only valid indices are produced during the computation can in this case easily be proved before, so here, no memory-safety is sacrificed¹; checking each access brings the time up to 1.96s, still significantly better than the bounds checking of the [array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array) library).

Bottom line: GHC needs (much) faster branching for the bounds-checking, and there's room for improvement in the optimiser, but in principle, "Haskell's approach (purity encoded in the type system) is compatible with efficiency, memory-safety and simplicity", we're just not yet there. For the time being, one has to decide how much of which point one is willing to sacrifice.

---

¹ Yes, that's a special case, in general omitting the bounds-check does sacrifice memory-safety, or it is at least harder to prove that it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply (best answer so far). *Oh, yeah, sorry it's row-major layout.* There isn't any difference between column-major and row-major, of course, but if one was allowed to mix and match different layouts, it could make a **big** difference in speed (in a super-naive implementation). That's why I specified it. I don't think your snarky tone is called for.

Comment: Yes, the snark level is higher than called for, I apologise. Your question (and comments) made a snarkier and more condescending impression on me this morning than it does (they do) now. I'm going to reduce it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `unsafeAt` and `unsafeWrite` in your Haskell code aren't memory-safe, are they? I'm comparing it to OpenJDK, which is supposed to be memory-safe. Do you think you should disclose this at least? Can you post a Haskell version that's memory-safe?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by memory-safe. Since I check the validity of indices in the programme, it's only unsafe if I goofed up. Technically, an additional range-check by the runtime environment doesn't guarantee memory-safety there either. If the implementors of the JVM goofed (yes, less likely than that I did), that could allow out-of-range accesses too. And explicitly disabling the range-checks with gcj didn't make a big difference. But I'll make one with `readArray` and `writeArray` too.

Comment: *And explicitly disabling the range-checks with gcj didn't make a big difference.* So, don't disable it (Who uses GCJ anyways. I believe it's abandonware) Sorry, but I can't accept your answer since your Haskell code isn't memory-safe. +1 though.

Comment: I'll check back in about 24h to see if any answers should be accepted.

Comment: By and large, one of the most well-written answers that I came across on SO.

Comment: I think this answer is not cache-efficient yet. If I change the Java for-loop to `for(i) for(k) for(j) c[i*cb+j] += a[i*ca+k]*b[k*cb+j]`, the Java version becomes 7 times faster. The *i-k-j* order is recommended e.g. [here](http://functionspace.org/articles/40). @DanielFischer can you check this?

Answer (score 12):

There are two angles to attack this problem on.

1. **Research,** along these lines, is ongoing. Now, there are plenty of Haskell programmers who are smarter than me; a fact I am constantly reminded of and humbled by. One of them may come by and correct me, but I don't know of any simple way to compose safe Haskell primitives into a top-of-the-line matrix multiplication routine. Those papers that you talk about sound like a good start.

   > However, I'm not a computer science researcher. I wonder if it's possible to keep simple things simple in Haskell.

   If you cite those papers, maybe we could help decipher them.
2. **Software engineering,** along these lines, is well-understood, straightforward, and even easy. A savvy Haskell coder would use a thin wrapper around BLAS, or look for such a wrapper in Hackage.

Deciphering cutting-edge research is an ongoing process that shifts knowledge from the researchers to the engineers. It was a computer science researcher, C.A.R. Hoare, who first discovered quicksort and published a paper about it. Today, it is a rare computer science graduate who can't personally implement quicksort from memory (at least, those that graduated recently).

### Bit of history

Almost this exact question has been asked in history a few times before.

1. Is it possible to write matrix arithmetic in Fortran that is as fast as assembly?
2. Is it possible to write matrix arithmetic in C that is as fast as Fortran?
3. Is it possible to write matrix arithmetic in Java that is as fast as C?
4. Is it possible to write matrix arithmetic in Haskell that is as fast as Java?

So far, the answer has always been, "not yet", followed by "close enough".  The advances that make this possible come from improvements in writing code, improvements to compilers, and improvements in the programming language itself.

As a specific example, C was not able to surpass Fortran in many real-world applications until C99 compilers became widespread in the past decade. In Fortran, different arrays are assumed to have distinct storage from each other, whereas in C this is not generally the case. Fortran compilers were therefore permitted to make optimizations that C compilers could not. Well, not until C99 came out and you could add the `restrict` qualifier to your code.

The Fortran compilers waited. Eventually the processors became complex enough that good assembly writing became more difficult, and the compilers became sophisticated enough that the Fortran was fast.

Then C programmers waited until the 2000s for the ability to write code that matched Fortran. Until that point, they used libraries written in Fortran or assembler (or both), or put up with the reduced speed.

The Java programers, likewise, had to wait for JIT compilers, and had to wait for specific optimizations to appear. JIT compilers were originally an esoteric research concept until they became a part of daily life. Bounds checking optimization was also necessary in order to avoid a test and branch for every array access.

### Back to Haskell

So, it is clear the Haskell programmers are "waiting", just like the Java, C, and Fortran programmers before them. What are we waiting for?

- Maybe we're just waiting for someone to write the code, and show us how it's done.
- Maybe we're waiting for the compilers to get better.
- Maybe we're waiting for an update to the Haskell language itself.

And maybe we're waiting for some combination of the above.

### About purity

Purity and monads get conflated a lot in Haskell. The reason for this is because in Haskell, impure functions always use the `IO` monad. For example, the `State` monad is 100% pure. So when you say, "pure" and "type signature does not use the `State` monad", those are actually completely independent and separate requirements.

*However,* you can also use the `IO` monad in the implementation of pure functions, and in fact, it's quite easy:

```
addSix :: Int -> Int
addSix n = unsafePerformIO $ return (n + 6)
```

Okay, yes, that's a stupid function, but it is pure. It's even obviously pure. The test for purity is twofold:

1. Does it give the same result for the same inputs? Yes.
2. Does it produce any semantically significant side effects? No.

The reason we like purity is because pure functions are easier to compose and manipulate than impure functions are. How they're implemented doesn't matter as much. I don't know if you're aware of this, but `Integer` and `ByteString` are both basically wrappers around impure C functions, even though the interface is pure. (There's work on a new implementation of `Integer`, I don't know how far it is.)

### Final answer

> The question is whether Haskell's approach (purity encoded in the type system) is compatible with efficiency, memory-safety and simplicity.

The answer to that part is "yes", since we can take simple functions from BLAS and put them in a pure, type-safe wrapper. The wrapper's type encodes the safety of the function, even though the Haskell compiler is unable to prove that the function's implementation is pure. Our use of `unsafePerformIO` in its implementation is both an acknowledgement that we have proven the purity of the function, and it is also a concession that we couldn't figure out a way to express that proof in Haskell's type system.

But the answer is also "not yet", since I don't know how to implement the function entirely in Haskell as such.

Research in this area is ongoing. People are looking at proof systems like [Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq) and new languages like [Agda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_%28programming_language%29), as well as developments in GHC itself. In order to see what kind of type system we'd need to prove that high-performance BLAS routines can be used safely. These tools can also be used with other languages like Java. For example, you could write a proof in Coq that your Java implementation is pure.

I apologize for the "yes and no" answer, but no other answer would recognize both the contributions of engineers (who care about "yes") and researchers (who care about "not yet").

**P.S.** Please cite the papers.

Comment: *I don't know how to implement the function entirely in Haskell as such.* I don't know whether to take this to mean that it's not currently possible, or that you personally can not do it (My interpretation would depend on how much Haskell experience you have - I don't know you) Someone suggested `St`, and another person suggested `traverse2`. Are they inappropriate? Please expand on your answer, if you have time.

Comment: "I don't know" is a statement about my knowledge, not about Haskell.  And I hope you are generous enough not to assume that it's because I'm bad at Haskell.

Comment: *People are looking at proof systems like Coq and new languages like Agda* Shooting sparrows with a cannon? I'm not exactly an Ada expert, but I'm pretty sure that Ada will let you encode purity in its type system and match Java in speed (by not being pure in the function body). Of course, its type system is very different from Haskell's.

Comment: *And I hope you are generous enough not to assume that it's because I'm bad at Haskell.* I'm merely suggesting this as a possible improvement to your answer. If an expert says "I don't know how to do X", it means that it must be pretty hard, or worse. If a newbie says the same thing, it's less meaningful. Your answer could use some clarification there.

Comment: @Oleg2718281828: It's hard not to feel insulted by your comments.  Talking about "shooting sparrows with a cannon" and asking whether I am a "newbie" are not appropriate points of discussion on Stack Overflow.  If you would like me to explain the purpose of formal verification, the reason why people use Agda and Coq, I can point you to a Wikipedia article.  If you want me to defend my credentials, I will simply deep-six my involvement with the question.

Comment: I know what Coq is (used it a little bit myself). No need for a wiki link. I'm just saying (apparently too colorfully) that Coq seems like an overkill for something like this. Re: your credentials: I'm neither questioning them, nor asking you to defend them. I'm asking you to state them in your answer, or rephrase your answer. I, or a future reader, could Google you and try to figure out what your "I don't know" implies based on Google's results, but I hope you'll agree that this is not SO's ideal MO. It's just a collaborative QA site.

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 - do you really mean Ada?  Dietrich mentioned Agda, not Ada.  They're completely different languages.  I'm pretty sure that Agda won't match Java for speed, especially as Agda programs aren't usually executed anyway.

Comment: For reference, this answer is the subject of a discussion over on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141983/someone-answers-i-dont-know-how-to-do-x

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 That's quite confusing. Why did you suddenly start discussing [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language))?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor DietrichEpp talked about using Coq to show that a function is pure (in some general CS programming language research context - Coq is not part of Haskell's type system). This seemed like an overkill to me, so I brought up Ada as an example of a very simple type system (compared to Haskell, not to mention Coq) that can track purity.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Wikipedia mentions this BTW. In the Ada lingo, a pure function is a "function". Everything else is a "procedure".

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 Right, with you now.

Answer (score 8):

Like Java, Haskell is not the best language for writing numerical code.

Haskell's numeric-heavy codegeneration is... average. It hasn't had the years of research behind it that the likes of Intel and GCC have.

What Haskell gives you instead, is a way to cleanly interface your "fast" code with the rest of your application. Remember that 3% of code is responsible for 97% of your application's running time. [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)

With Haskell, you have a way to call these highly optimized functions in a way that interfaces extremely nicely with the rest of your code: via the very nice C Foreign Function Interface. In fact, if you so desired, you could write your numeric code in the assembly language of your architecture and get even more performance! Dipping into C for performance-heavy parts of your application isn't a bug - it's a feature.

But I digress.

By having these highly optimized functions isolated, and with a similar interface to the rest of your Haskell code, you could perform high level optimizations with Haskell's very powerful rewrite rules, which allow you to write rules such as `reverse . reverse == id` which automagically reduce complex expressions at compile time [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS). This leads to extremely fast, purely functional, and easy-to-use libraries like Data.Text [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Fortran_Compiler) and Data.Vector [4].

By combining high and low levels of optimization, we end up with a much more optimized implementation, with each half ("C/asm", and "Haskell") relatively easy to read. The low level optimization is done in its native tongue (C or assembly), the high level optimization gets a special [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (Haskell rewrite rules), and the rest of the code is oblivious to it completely.

In conclusion, yes, Haskell can be faster than Java. But it cheats by going through C for the raw [FLOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS). This is much harder to do in Java (as well as having a much higher overhead for Java's FFI), so it's avoided. In Haskell, it's natural. If your application spends an exorbitant amount of time doing numeric calculations, then maybe instead of looking at Haskell or Java, you look at Fortran for your needs. If your application spends a large portion of its time in a tiny part of performance-sensitive code, then the Haskell FFI is your best bet. If your application doesn't spend any time in numeric code... then use whatever you like. =)

Haskell (nor Java, for that matter) isn't Fortran.

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) These numbers were made up, but you get my point.

[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/papers/CLS07.html

[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Fortran_Compiler) http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text

[4] http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector

---

Now that that's out of the way, to answer your actual question:

No, it's not currently smart to write your matrix multiplications in Haskell. At the moment, REPA is the canonical way to do this [5]. The implementation partially breaks memory safety, (they use unsafeSlice), but the "broken memory safety" is isolated to that function, actually very safe (but not easily verified by the compiler), and easy to remove if things go wrong (replace "unsafeSlice" with "slice").

But this is Haskell! Very rarely are the performance characteristics of a function to be taken in isolation. That can be a bad thing (in the case of space leaks), or a very, very good thing.

Although the matrix multiplication algorithm used is naive, it will perform worse in a raw benchmark. But rarely does our code look like benchmarks.

What if you were a scientist with millions of data points and want to multiply huge matrices? [7]

For those people, we have mmultP [6]. This performs matrix multiplication, but is data-parallel, and subject to REPA's nested data parallelism. Also note that the code is essentially unchanged from the sequential version.

For those people that don't multiply huge matrices, and instead multiply lots of little matrices, there tends to be other code interacting with said matrices. Possibly cutting it up into column vectors and finding their dot products, maybe finding its eigenvalues, maybe something else entirely. Unlike C, Haskell knows that although you like to solve problems in isolation, the most efficient solution usually isn't found there.

Like ByteString, Text, and Vector, REPA arrays are subject to fusion. [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) You should actually read [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) by the way - it's a very well written paper. This, combined with aggressive inlining of relevant code and REPA's highly parallel nature allows us to express these high-level mathematical concepts with very advanced high-level optimizations behind the scenes.

Although a method of writing an efficient matrix multiplication in pure functional languages isn't currently know, we can come somewhat close (no automatic vectorization, a few excessive dereferences to get to the actual data, etc.), but nothing near what [IFORT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Fortran_Compiler) or GCC can do. But program's don't exist on an island, and making the island as a whole perform well is much, much easier in Haskell than Java.

[5] http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa-algorithms/3.2.1.1/doc/html/src/Data-Array-Repa-Algorithms-Matrix.html#mmultS

[6] http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa-algorithms/3.2.1.1/doc/html/src/Data-Array-Repa-Algorithms-Matrix.html#mmultP

[7] Acutally, the best way to do this is by using the GPU. There are a few GPU DSLs available for Haskell which make this possible to do natively. They're really neat!

Comment: *[Haskell] hasn't had the years of research behind it that the likes of intel and gcc have.* Is there a typo there or do you mean it exactly as written? Google Scholar finds 1,000+ papers with all of the following terms: GHC, Haskell, performance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I hate to be a stickler, but memory-safety (and thus no FFI) was a specific requirement. I think this should have been a comment, as you are not attempting to answer my question.

Comment: Nice.  Your comment about rewrite rules and using the "high view" makes me think that Haskell is in some ways, a successor to languages like APL.

Comment: @Oleg2718281828: When I say years of research, I mean specifically in low-level codegen for various platforms in use today. There is no current compiler out there that can match the excellent job Intel did with ifort.

Also, I don't see why your numerical code is doing heavy memory manipulation. If it's not immediately obvious what you're doing, then you didn't break down the problem enough. For example, I don't see anyone's mmul segfaulting anytime soon.

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 he answered precisely your question, but in a different way than you expected. The bolded text at the end states "The question is whether Haskell's approach (purity encoded in the type system) is compatible with efficiency, memory-safety and simplicity." This answer indicates that the "Haskell approach" is not only purity encoded in the type system, but also allowing the programmer to provide a pure interface to code written in a low-level language, which stitches those three features together quite nicely. "memory-safety" can be proven, even though its not guaranteed in C.